# Does Image.fromarray() accept 16 bit image

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, 16-bit

I am trying to apply the function Image.fromarray() to a 16 bit image but i amgetting this error : TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <f4

I know that this error occurs when the values are between  0 and 1 but in my case they are between 0 and 65535.

Comment: Assuming your image is a Numpy array called `NA`, please `print(NA.shape, NA.dtype)` and click [edit] and add the results to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Also `print(NA.min(), NA.max())`